# Count rows between occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with several columns: Employee|Date|SickDay

Each day, regardless if the employee is at work, an entry is recorded. However, I am trying to find the number of entries between when an employee was sick. For example, if there are 20 rows total, and on the  1st row, 10th row, and 20th row the employee was sick, I want to find the average number of times between dates that this employee is out sick. I have tried a few things but I am just stuck.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Employees
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM employees
        WHERE SickDay = 1
            AND Employee = James
        )
```

Comment: Please see the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data & desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `LAG()` function is what you want. Something like:

```
SELECT Date AS SickDate,
  LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS PrevSickDate
FROM
  (SELECT Date FROM Employees WHERE Employee = 123 AND Sick = 1) AS S
```